# UMMORG/Mirror Networking - Moving A Connection From World To Lobby

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, unity3d-mirror

I have been working for some time on a project using the UMMORG framework, which is built on Mirror networking. However, as of recent, I have been having an issue I just cannot solve.

In my project, when a player character is killed, I want the player to be moved from the game world back to the lobby. Or, in more technical terms, for the player's NetworkConnection to me moved from the Network State 'World' to the Network State 'Lobby.'

I have tried many times, but have been unable to find a way to do this. The consistent issue is with the player NetworkConnection not being found as a key in the Lobby dictionary. However, attempts to manually add the player NetworkConnection to the Lobby dictionary have failed. I'm assuming that Mirror requires a specific process to move a connection back to the lobby, but I just can't figure it out!

TLDR: How can I move a NetworkConnection in Network State 'World' to Network State 'Lobby?'

Thank you so much for your help! I will be checking this thread as often as I can, so if I haven't provided enough information, I would be happy to provide more. I have not changed any of the netcode in my UMMORG project, so if you have found a solution for this in your UMMORG or Mirror project, I would love to hear it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Did you use MatchInterestManager?

I used MatchInterestManager and attach NetworkMatch to my player script.
Whenever I needed to change player state (for example from Lobby to Game or Game to Lobby), I simply change NetworkMatch.matchID from *"lobby".toGuid* to *"gameName".toGuid*.

Feel free to leave comments, and I'll do my best to answer.